# android : fetching images from built in gallery

Tags: android, gridview, image-resizing

I am trying out [this example link](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html) to display images from built-in Gallery in a GridView.

This is working fine. But all the images are a bit small. I tried making them bigger by changing in below code from 70,70 to 100,100.

```
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        if (bitmap != null) 
        {
            newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
            bitmap.recycle();

            if (newBitmap != null) 
            {
                publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
            }
        }
```

But This is not working. The images are of same size. How do I make them bigger?
Please Suggest.Thanks!

Comment: you scalling images to 70,70 so it may be

Comment: I have tried changing even that.No changes.

Comment: You are scaling from 70 to 100 and that's fine. But what's the size of view you are trying to display images in?

Comment: what is the original size?

Comment: I don't know the original size because it is picked from a query. 

Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // Return all rows
                    null,       
                    null);

Answer (score 0):

You may be modifying the size of the Bitmap, but you are still rendering it into a small cell on your grid, dictated by these lines:

In `setupViews`:

```
sdcardImages.setNumColumns(display.getWidth()/95);
```

In `ImageAdapter`:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
imageView.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position).getBitmap());
```

You will need to modify these values in order to render your images at a larger size.